# Parabolic rescaling and time shift

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Assume $u(x,t)$ is solution of
$$
\partial_t u(x,t)  =\Delta_x u(x,t)
$$
for $t\in [a,b]$. Seemly, there is a method (called parabolic rescaling and time shift)  can make a solution $\hat u(\hat x, \hat t)$ such that
$$
\partial_\hat t \hat u(\hat x,\hat t)  =\Delta_\hat x \hat u(\hat x,\hat t)
$$
for $\hat  t\in [0,1]$.

What I try: let $\hat t = \frac{t-a}{b-a}$ and $\hat u (x,\hat t)= u(x, a+\hat t (b-a))=u(x,t)$, then I have
$$
\partial_{\hat t} \hat u(x,\hat t) = (b-a)\Delta_x \hat u (x, \hat t)
$$
Then, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You are making the transformation $[a, b] \ni t \to a + (b - a) t := \hat{t} \in [0, 1]$ and hence $$\partial_{t} u \to (b - a) \partial_{\hat{t}} u \tag 1$$ Therefore, you need to rescale $x$ in such a way that taking the Laplacian of $u$ yields a prefactor $(b - a)$. Perhaps let $x \to \lambda x := \hat{x}$ for some arbitrary $\lambda$, compute derivatives using the chain rule as was done above in $(1)$ and see what $\lambda$ needs to be.

Comment: @MatthewCassell  Thanks your help.  $\lambda=1/ \sqrt{b-a}$.

Comment: @MatthewCassell  For complex equation, is there similar method?  For example, the Ricci flow $\partial_t g = -2Ric$.

Comment: How did you get $\lambda = (b - a)^{-1/2}$? \begin{align} \partial_{x} u &\to \lambda \partial_{\hat{x}} u \\ \partial_{x x} u &\to \lambda^{2} \partial_{\hat{x} \hat{x}} u \\ \implies 0 &= \partial_{t} u - \partial_{x x} u \\ &= (b - a) \partial_{\hat{t}} u - \lambda^{2} \partial_{\hat{x} \hat{x}} u \end{align} and so you require $\lambda^{2} = b - a$ for invariance.